# How to turn off PumaWorkerKiller in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I am using `PumaWorkerKiller` using this code in `config/puma.rb`:

```
  before_fork do
    PumaWorkerKiller.config do |config|
      config.ram           = 512 # mb
    end
    PumaWorkerKiller.start
  end
```

I want to stop it running on development mode. I tried to do this by putting a guard clause in like

```
if Rails.env.production?
  # PumaWorkerKiller code goes here
end
```

This works in development, but triggers an error in production, to the effect that `Rails` is an unknown constant. Presumably it is loading earlier in production than development.

How do I turn off `PumaWorkerKiller` in development but keep it working in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puma should know what environment it is in without referencing rails.

Here's how my `config/puma.rb` looks, omitting unrelated lines:

```
environment ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"

before_fork do
  require "puma_worker_killer"

  PumaWorkerKiller.config do |config|
    config.ram           = (ENV["PUMA_WORKER_KILLER_RAM"] || 1024).to_i # mb
  end
  PumaWorkerKiller.start unless get(:environment) == "development"
end
```